# pvs/vgs/lvs and block device size not matching

Tags: lvm

I have a LV with a filesystem on it.  The LUNs behind this filesystem have been grown on SAN, as have the PV, VG, and LV.

But the block device seems not to match so my resize2fs fails.

I never saw this before, what gives?

I am using Oracle Linux 6.5

```
# rpm -qa | egrep 'mdadm|lvm'
mdadm-3.2.5-4.el6_4.3.x86_64
lvm2-2.02.98-9.el6_4.3.x86_64
lvm2-libs-2.02.98-9.el6_4.3.x86_64
```

Old size was 30G.  new size is 45G

```
# pvs
  PV         VG         Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/md0   vg_app   lvm2 a--   45.00g       0

# vgs
  VG         #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  vg_app     1   1   0 wz--n-  45.00g       0

# lvs
  LV       VG         Attr      LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_app vg_app   -wi-ao--- 45.00g

# vgdisplay vg_app
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_app
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               45.00 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              11519
  Alloc PE / Size       11519 / 45.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               McCXhj-nUuJ-ojpD-mnkc-2foM-oxnJ-mIb9pW

# lvdisplay /dev/vg_app/lv_app
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_app/lv_app
  LV Name                lv_app
  VG Name                vg_app
  LV UUID                Mx0rhZ-PnmL-cb3H-iF81-hs0u-20Zj-X5IUme
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ,
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                45.00 GiB
  Current LE             11519
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/vg_app/lv_app
31138512896

# blockdev --rereadpt /dev/vg_app/lv_app
BLKRRPART: Invalid argument
#
```